# PhoneGap faz somente jogos?

Tags: apache-cordova

Tenho estudado arduamente programação para Android em Java, sendo tem me preocupado a questão de programar em Java e somente ganhar uma parcela do mercado porque os programas em Java não roda em Windows Phone, então soube do PhoneGap que é multiplataforma pode fazer jogos em IOS, Windows Phone e Android. sendo que meu objetivo não é fazer jogos e sim aplicativos corporativos como por exemplo um controle de caixa.

A maioria dos cursos de PhoneGap  é para treina as pessoas para desenvolver jogos sendo que eu queria saber se aprendendo a mexer com PhoneGap  poderia também desenvolver programas corporativos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não, o PhoneGap consegue produzir qualquer tipo de aplicativo. O pessoal mostra jogo por uma questão de interesse apenas, muita gente quer fazer jogos para celular.

O PhoneGap é uma ferramenta que permite usar HTML e JavaScript para produzir aplicativos multiplataforma, assim sendo, você pode produzir qualquer coisa que possa ser feito com HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Não, o PhoneGap (Projeto da Adobe) assim como o Cordova (Projeto da Apache), são nada mais que frameworks de desenvolvimento que permitem que você empacote qualquer aplicação feita com HTML, CSS e JavaScript, no formato nativo para distribuição em qualquer uma das plataformas suportadas pelo projeto.

Outra grande vantagem é disponibilizarem uma serie de funções para facilitar o desenvolvimento entre os diversos dispositivos por exemplo uma função para acessar de forma unificada a câmera do dispositivo, independente de qual sistema operacional esteja rodando no dispositivo.

> ... com PhoneGap poderia também desenvolver programas corporativos?

Respondendo a pergunta, Sim, e você pode escolher utiliza-lo para empacotar ou se também irá utilizar as funções para acesso as funcionalidades do dispositivo.

Quando a performance isso depende totalmente de como é  a arquitetura do aplicativo e de quais bibliotecas você escolher para desenvolver o seu aplicativo.

Aconselho instalar node, git ,ant, cordova e criar um projeto teste para ter uma noção do que a ferramenta é capaz. Tem muitos cursos e tutoriais online.

Answer (score -2):

O PhoneGap é um Framework livre e de codigo aberto, que aceita qualquer tipo de 
aplicação Mobile, como por exemplo jogos, sistemas de vendas e muitos outros.

Comment: Desculpe, mas não consigo ver a sua motivação para responder a pergunta, as demais respostas já falam basicamente o que você disse e com muito mais, você praticamente só comentou algo, não respondeu a nada, ainda mais levando em consideração que a pergunta é de 2014, realmente seria mais interessente e proveitoso para a comunidade se você optasse por detalhar sobre o PhoneGap. PS: Só pra constar PhoneGap NÃO É FRAMEWORK, é um "kit" de desenvolvimento, o Cordova sim é o framework.